# Как узнать, что пользователь перешел из контекстной рекламы?

Tags: php, реклама

Как изменить информацию, на сайте если пользователь перешел из контекстной рекламы. Нужно поменять телефон. Наведите на мысль в какую сторону копать.

Comment: А `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` не смотрели, она на сайт где размещена реклама или может все таки провайдер рекламы ...

Answer (score 1):

При переходе с контекстной рекламы можно ориентироваться на `GET` параметры. В `php` можно сделать следующие проверки:

```
// Для Яндекса
if (isset($_GET['utm_source']) && $_GET['utm_source'] == 'yandex.direct') {
    // Меняем контент
}

// Для Google
if (isset($_GET['gclid']) {
    // Меняем контент
}
```

Comment: Ссылку такого формата сделать не получится из-за seo. Но благодаря вашему ответу я заметил что припереходе с яндекса, в браузерной строке появляется строчка (?utm_source=yandex.direct) по ней можно ориентироваться. Но вот с гугла, какая-то ерунда (?gclid=) или поэтому gclid тоже можно ориентироваться?

Comment: @harley,в случае с `google` можно ориентироваться просто на существование переменной. Изменил свой ответ.

Comment: @harley, и предлагаю добавить `GET` параметры гугла и яндекса в Ваш вопрос.